# Loading MathJax in JavaFX WebView

Tags: javascript, java, webview, javafx

I have an HTML file inside my project package. In other words:

```
com/package/name/index.html
```

I am using JavaFX `WebEngine` to load it into a `WebView`:

```
    String url = MyApp.class.getResource("index.html").toExternalForm();  
    webView.getEngine().load(url);
```

`MyApp` is in the same package as the HTMl file, so this works fine. The page is displayed as expected.

Now I want to call a javascript library. In particular, MathJax.

I have put the MathJax folder in the same package, so the path to the `.js` file is

```
com/package/name/MATHJAX/MathJax.js?
```

Anyway, inside the HTML file I have written

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MATHJAX/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

If I were to run this file in Chrome or FireFox, it would open fine and parse my mathematics.

But if I try to open this in JavaFX's `WebView`, the parse does not occur (so I assume that the MathJax library is not being loaded).

What is the correct path to load MathJax, then?

---

**Progress:**

Changing the `index.html` file to

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","MathMenu.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    MathMenu: {
      delay: 600
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MATHJAX/MathJax.js"></script>
```

Will effectively reach the `MathJax.js` file. However, it won't be able to load the rest of MathJax, throwing errors like this:

> File failed to load: jar:file:/Users/me/Program.jar!/com/package/name/MATHJAX/extensions/MathMenu.js

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's not a dup.  Anyway, I just tried loading a page including MathJax in my own `WebView` and it loaded fine.  Looking at your progress, are you just not configuring `MathMenu`?  I think you have to add it to your `extensions` and add to your config as described here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/MathMenu.html

Comment: @heenenee Hm. I have added it now (edited my question), but it would seem to be making the same error: `File failed to load: jar:file:/Users/me/Program.jar!/com/package/name/MATHJAX/extensions/MathMenu.js` - you were able to load both your `index.html` and MathJax from within the JAR itself? May I have a copy of your project?

Comment: I did, but I didn't use `MathMenu`.  It's part of a larger project that I use for testing random things, gimme a few minutes and I'll put it into a separate project for sharing.

Comment: @heenenee Thanks! Really appreciate it. Frankly I don't need MathMenu either, but for some reason MathJax seems to be trying to load it anyway even if my config doesn't have it, so I guess the best way to fix it is comparing with your project.

Comment: Oh man sorry Voldemort.  I was wrong and I didn't see it until I broke it out into a separate project.  My first project was loading resources from an exploded directory and not a jar.  Well, now I see a similar error as yours anyway.

Comment: @heenenee Haha, oh well - I'll just see if someone answers this question :]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using cdn to include the js?

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?    config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```